# usb will not boot from Acer but will on HP

Tags: boot, usb

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on (Pony) USB. I installed it on Window 10 Partition HP Desktop ; no Problem. Then I tried to install on Acer Desktop .It would not go passed Menuentry--Blank screen.  I have installed Linux on Acer before Many times from DVDs. Acer is Intel i5 8GB Ram .  Reset Bios ( Removed & replaced CMOS ). Boot order OK. Secure Boot OK. In addition I put Puppy Linux on another USB (Toshiba). That one booted on Acer; No Problem. Why won't Acer Boot Ubuntu from Good Usb ( Booted on HP )?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it wouldn't go past 'menuentry'?

Comment: Before  ubuntu boots it gives a splash entry  of which i could select to boot .or it will time out and boot . either way it does not boot....

Comment: What tool did you use to make Live USB? some like mkusb can make USB that only boots BIOS mode some like Rufus can make USB that only boots UEFI mode, however most will make a USB that by default will boot in either mode. There may be many reasons the USB is not booting, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot

Answer (score 0):

Your installer is an `EFI` only one when you try to use it on a `BIOS` based computer it will not work. Some are universal some are not, for instance if using `Rufus` on a windows machine to create the installer you are asked which option you want for it.